# Export unit test result into a file with Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

Is there a way to automate the saving of the unit test results in Xcode?

I'd like to save them into a folder each time I run them

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to automate the testing altogether. This isn't easy, but [a hack](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/06/running-xcode-4-unit-tests-from-the-command-line/) can do this for you. You can then simply pipe the output to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jenkins to build your app with Xcode plugin ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin )

Jenkins can save unit test result for you or send it by mail.